# PHP - error when using socket_recv

Tags: php, sockets

I have a socket error when running the socket_recv inside this function:

```
function readByteXByteSIBmsg() {
    $msg = "";
    $buf="";
    try {
     while( $ret=socket_recv($this->kpSocket,$buf,8192,0)){
        $msg.=$buf;
        if($ret<8192) break;
     }


    $this->deb_print("KpCore:readByteXByteSIBmsg:READ LOOP TERMINATED");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        err_print("KPICore:readByteXByteSIBmsg:Exception on EVENT  HANDLER:RECEIVE:\n" . $e);
        $this->$KP_ERROR_ID = $this->ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT;
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

This is the text of the error:

```
PHP Warning:  socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [11]: Resource temporarily unavailable in /home/luca/Documenti/Tesi/M3 Agent Page/lib/KPICore.php on line 236
```

(line 236 is the line with the socket_recv call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `EAGAIN` (or `EWOULDBLOCK`, sometimes those are the same error)  and means that the socket is non-blocking and that there is nothing to read at the moment. You can busy-wait while you have that error until you read something, or you use some other method to find out if there is data to read before trying to receive.

Comment: Been a few years, but I'm curious. How exactly might I go about using "*some other method to find out if there is data to read*"?

Comment: @i336_ [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) comes to mind. :)

Comment: D'oh. Of course. Yeah, I didn't fully grasp the "oh if you get `EAGAIN` you just fall back into `select()` and let it tell you" thing initially... heh. Thanks :)