# fwrite returning (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: php, sockets, centos, fwrite, fsockopen

I have a simple php script that sends emails using PMTA

```
set_time_limit(0);

if ($socket = fsockopen("_IP_",2025,$errno, $errstr, 15)) {

    fwrite($socket, "EHLO $ehlo\r\n");

    foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {   

        fwrite($socket, "MAIL FROM: $from\r\n");

        fwrite($socket, "RCPT TO: $email\r\n");

        fwrite($socket, "DATA\r\n");

        fwrite($socket, implode("\r\n", $headers)."\r\n\r\n".$body."\r\n");

        fwrite($socket, ".\r\n");

    }

    fwrite($socket, "QUIT\r\n");

    fclose($socket);

}
```

after around 3000 email fwrite will return with a warning Resource temporarily unavailable

```
PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 187 bytes failed with errno=11 Resource temporarily unavailable in /var/www/html/app/send.php on line 340
```

Any ideas, where the problem is? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

errno=11 is socket report EAGAIN error that on nonblock pipes TCP buffer fully. The error handler should catch the EAGAIN error (errno=11), so any debugging assistance you. See [PHP - error when using socket_recv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610502/php-error-when-using-socket-recv)